# Optimize a query with small LIMIT, predicate on one column and order by another

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization, postgresql-9.3, performance, postgresql-performance

I'm using Postgres 9.3.4 and I have 4 queries that have very similar inputs but have vastly different response times:

#### Query #1

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT posts.* FROM posts
WHERE posts.source_id IN (19082, 19075, 20705, 18328, 19110, 24965, 18329, 27600, 17804, 20717, 27598, 27599)
AND posts.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY external_created_at desc
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
                                                                                 QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..585.44 rows=100 width=1041) (actual time=326092.852..507360.199 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using index_posts_on_external_created_at on posts  (cost=0.43..14871916.35 rows=2542166 width=1041) (actual time=326092.301..507359.524 rows=100 loops=1)
         Filter: (source_id = ANY ('{19082,19075,20705,18328,19110,24965,18329,27600,17804,20717,27598,27599}'::integer[]))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 6913925
 Total runtime: 507361.944 ms
```

#### Query #2

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT posts.* FROM posts
WHERE posts.source_id IN (5202, 5203, 661, 659, 662, 627)
AND posts.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY external_created_at desc
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;                                            

    QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=31239.64..31239.89 rows=100 width=1041) (actual time=2.004..2.038 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=31239.64..31261.26 rows=8648 width=1041) (actual time=2.003..2.017 rows=100 loops=1)
         Sort Key: external_created_at
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 80kB
         ->  Index Scan using index_posts_on_source_id on posts  (cost=0.44..30909.12 rows=8648 width=1041) (actual time=0.024..1.063 rows=944 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (source_id = ANY ('{5202,5203,661,659,662,627}'::integer[]))
               Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 109
 Total runtime: 2.125 ms
```

#### Query #3

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT posts.* FROM posts
WHERE posts.source_id IN (14790, 14787, 32928, 14796, 14791, 15503, 14789, 14772, 15506, 14794, 15543, 31615, 15507, 15508, 14800)
AND posts.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY external_created_at desc
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
                                                                             QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..821.25 rows=100 width=1041) (actual time=19.224..55.599 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using index_posts_on_external_created_at on posts  (cost=0.43..14930351.58 rows=1818959 width=1041) (actual time=19.213..55.529 rows=100 loops=1)
         Filter: (source_id = ANY ('{14790,14787,32928,14796,14791,15503,14789,14772,15506,14794,15543,31615,15507,15508,14800}'::integer[]))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 414
 Total runtime: 55.683 ms
```

#### Query #4

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT posts.* FROM posts
WHERE posts.source_id IN (18766, 18130, 18128, 18129, 19705, 28252, 18264, 18126, 18767, 27603, 28657, 28654, 28655, 19706, 18330)
AND posts.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY external_created_at desc
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
                                                                            QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..69055.29 rows=100 width=1041) (actual time=26.094..320.626 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using index_posts_on_external_created_at on posts  (cost=0.43..14930351.58 rows=21621 width=1041) (actual time=26.093..320.538 rows=100 loops=1)
         Filter: (source_id = ANY ('{18766,18130,18128,18129,19705,28252,18264,18126,18767,27603,28657,28654,28655,19706,18330}'::integer[]))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 6156
 Total runtime: 320.778 ms
```

All 4 are the same, apart from looking at posts with different `source_id`s.

Three of the four end up using the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_external_created_at ON posts USING btree (external_created_at DESC)
WHERE (deleted_at IS NULL);
```

And the #2 uses this index:

```
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_source_id ON posts USING btree (source_id);
```

What's interesting to me, is that of the 3 that use the `index_posts_on_external_created_at` index, two are quite fast, while the other (#1) is insanely slow.

Query #2 has way less posts than the other 3 do, so that might explain why it uses the `index_posts_on_source_id` index instead. However, if I get rid of the `index_posts_on_external_created_at` index, the other 3 queries are extremely slow when forced to use the `index_posts_on_source_id` index.

Here's my definition of the posts table:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    source_id integer,
    message text,
    image text,
    external_id text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    external text,
    like_count integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    comment_count integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    external_created_at timestamp without time zone,
    deleted_at timestamp without time zone,
    poster_name character varying(255),
    poster_image text,
    poster_url character varying(255),
    poster_id text,
    position integer,
    location character varying(255),
    description text,
    video text,
    rejected_at timestamp without time zone,
    deleted_by character varying(255),
    height integer,
    width integer
);
```

I've tried using `CLUSTER posts USING index_posts_on_external_created_at`

Which is essentially an index that orders by external_created_at and this seems to be the only effective method I've found. However, I am unable to use this on production as it causes a global lock for several hours while it runs. I'm on heroku, so I can't install [pg_repack](http://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/) or anything like that.

Why would the #1 query be so slow, and others be really quick? What can I do to mitigate this?

EDIT: Here are my queries without the `LIMIT` and `ORDER`

#### Query #1

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT posts.* FROM posts
WHERE posts.source_id IN (19082, 19075, 20705, 18328, 19110, 24965, 18329, 27600, 17804, 20717, 27598, 27599)
AND posts.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY external_created_at desc;
                                                                        QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=7455044.81..7461163.56 rows=2447503 width=1089) (actual time=94903.143..95110.898 rows=238975 loops=1)
   Sort Key: external_created_at
   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 81440kB
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on posts  (cost=60531.78..1339479.50 rows=2447503 width=1089) (actual time=880.150..90988.460 rows=238975 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (source_id = ANY ('{19082,19075,20705,18328,19110,24965,18329,27600,17804,20717,27598,27599}'::integer[]))
         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5484857
         Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 3108465
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_posts_on_source_id  (cost=0.00..59919.90 rows=3267549 width=0) (actual time=877.904..877.904 rows=3347440 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (source_id = ANY ('{19082,19075,20705,18328,19110,24965,18329,27600,17804,20717,27598,27599}'::integer[]))
 Total runtime: 95534.724 ms
```

#### Query #2

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT posts.* FROM posts
WHERE posts.source_id IN (5202, 5203, 661, 659, 662, 627)
AND posts.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY external_created_at desc;
                                                                     QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=36913.72..36935.85 rows=8852 width=1089) (actual time=212.450..212.549 rows=944 loops=1)
   Sort Key: external_created_at
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 557kB
   ->  Index Scan using index_posts_on_source_id on posts  (cost=0.44..32094.90 rows=8852 width=1089) (actual time=1.732..209.590 rows=944 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (source_id = ANY ('{5202,5203,661,659,662,627}'::integer[]))
         Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 109
 Total runtime: 214.507 ms
```

#### Query #3

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT posts.* FROM posts
WHERE posts.source_id IN (14790, 14787, 32928, 14796, 14791, 15503, 14789, 14772, 15506, 14794, 15543, 31615, 15507, 15508, 14800)
AND posts.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY external_created_at desc;
                                                                        QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=5245032.87..5249894.14 rows=1944508 width=1089) (actual time=131032.952..134342.372 rows=1674072 loops=1)
   Sort Key: external_created_at
   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 854864kB
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on posts  (cost=48110.86..1320005.55 rows=1944508 width=1089) (actual time=605.648..91351.334 rows=1674072 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (source_id = ANY ('{14790,14787,32928,14796,14791,15503,14789,14772,15506,14794,15543,31615,15507,15508,14800}'::integer[]))
         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5304550
         Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 879414
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_posts_on_source_id  (cost=0.00..47624.73 rows=2596024 width=0) (actual time=602.744..602.744 rows=2553486 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (source_id = ANY ('{14790,14787,32928,14796,14791,15503,14789,14772,15506,14794,15543,31615,15507,15508,14800}'::integer[]))
 Total runtime: 136176.868 ms
```

#### Query #4

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT posts.* FROM posts
WHERE posts.source_id IN (18766, 18130, 18128, 18129, 19705, 28252, 18264, 18126, 18767, 27603, 28657, 28654, 28655, 19706, 18330)
AND posts.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY external_created_at desc;
                                                                       QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=102648.92..102704.24 rows=22129 width=1089) (actual time=15225.250..15256.931 rows=51408 loops=1)
   Sort Key: external_created_at
   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 35456kB
   ->  Index Scan using index_posts_on_source_id on posts  (cost=0.45..79869.91 rows=22129 width=1089) (actual time=3.975..14803.320 rows=51408 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (source_id = ANY ('{18766,18130,18128,18129,19705,28252,18264,18126,18767,27603,28657,28654,28655,19706,18330}'::integer[]))
         Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 54
 Total runtime: 15397.453 ms
```

Postgres memory settings:

```
name, setting, unit
'default_statistics_target','100',''
'effective_cache_size','16384','8kB'
'maintenance_work_mem','16384','kB'
'max_connections','100',''
'random_page_cost','4',NULL
'seq_page_cost','1',NULL
'shared_buffers','16384','8kB'
'work_mem','1024','kB'
```

Database stats:

```
Total Posts: 20,997,027
Posts where deleted_at is null: 15,665,487
Distinct source_id's: 22,245
Max number of rows per single source_id: 1,543,950
Min number of rows per single source_id: 1
Most source_ids in a single query: 21
Distinct external_created_at: 11,146,151
```

Comment: Please try running the queries and posting the explain/analyze plans here when you remove the LIMIT lines.

Comment: @JoishiBodio Sure thing. I've edited my question and added these query plans to the bottom.

Comment: See some great answers I got for a similar (although not identical) problem: **[Can spatial index help a “range - order by - limit” query](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query)**

Comment: `external merge  Disk: <size>` is consistent across all the long queries.  This is a performance killer .. it's saying that the data set returned is too large to do an in-memory sort.  What are your postgres server memory settings?  I find it odd that it doesn't show it when the LIMIT is present, considering that (I assume) it's still happening (behind the scenes).

Comment: @JoishiBodio I was wondering about that too, but I never saw the Disk being used for the smaller limits. All of my memory settings are the defaults. Is there an easy way to view all of them? some `psql` command?

Comment: I dunno if you can view them in psql .. they're in your postgres.conf file (all in the same section, thankfully).  The default memory settings are ridiculously tiny (I assume to that it can run safely on pretty much any machine at the start).  `https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server`  I don't actually know if that's the root cause of the slow queries (@YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ could be spot on) .. but it's worth looking at, at least.

Comment: apparently on the link I posted you can put `SHOW ALL` or `SHOW <setting>` or `SELECT * FROM pg_settings` to view them within psql.

Comment: @JoishiBodio thank you! I've included my previous pg memory settings in the second edit of my question. I tried updating my `work_mem` to 96MB and re-ran Query #1 in my first edit (without `LIMIT` or `OFFSET`) but I still get `Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 81440kB`. I double checked that my `work_mem` was 96MB and it was. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to up effective cache size and shared buffers as well...  This is starting to get long.  heh.  Give that a try, and if it works I'll post the info as an answer - if not, it'll have to be someone else with a solution.  :)  Good luck!

Comment: This query is hard to optimize. You provided good information, but we would still need to know more. In particular: cardinalities and value frequencies. How many rows in `posts`? How many of them with `deleted_at IS NULL`? How many distinct `source_id`? **Number of rows (min / max) per `source_id`? And how many `source_id` are referenced in a single query at most?** Values in `external_created_at` are (mostly) unique? Or large patches of identical timestamps? How much write load? How many concurrent sessions? How much RAM available?

Comment: Two more important questions: `LIMIT` isn't going to be higher than 100? And do you have a table holding all distinct `source_id` - a `source` table?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks for your help. I've edited the question to include the stats you're looking for. As for your additional questions: Yes, the `external_created_at` are about 50% distinct (see stats). There is little write load / concurrent sessions as I am doing all this testing from my development machine. 4GB of ram available. `LIMIT` will never be greater than 100. Yes, there is a `source` table as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### General advice

All the general advice for performance optimization applies. Default settings are very conservative and some of these resource settings are ***way to low*** for tables with millions of rows (`work_mem` in particular). You need to configure your RDBMS to make use of available RAM wisely. [The Postgres Wiki is a good starting point.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) This is beyond the scope of a single question here.

***However***, the query I suggest below only needs very moderate resource settings.

Also increase the statistics target for `source_id` to have more detailed statistics on the crucial column:

```
ALTER TABLE posts ALTER COLUMN source_id SET STATISTICS 2000;  -- or similar
```

Then: `ANALYZE posts;`

More:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8229000/939860)

You could optimize storage some more (for minor gains):

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

### Query

The query itself is hard to optimize. Refer to @ypercube's related question for advanced performance optimization:

- [Can spatial index help a "range - order by - limit" query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query)

There is a **simple method *if ...***

- the number of distinct `source_id` per query is reasonably small
- and the `LIMIT` is also reasonably small.

... which is true for your case according to your added details.

The only **index** you need for the query below:

```
CREATE INDEX posts_special_idx ON posts (source_id, external_created_at DESC)
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
```

Example based on your query #1:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   unnest('{19082, 19075, 20705, 18328, 19110, 24965, 18329, 27600
              , 17804, 20717, 27598, 27599}'::int[]) s(source_id)
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   posts
   WHERE  source_id = s.source_id
   AND    deleted_at IS NULL
   ORDER  BY external_created_at DESC
   LIMIT  100
   ) p
ORDER  BY p.external_created_at DESC
LIMIT  100;
```

This is emulating a ***loose index scan***, similar to what's discussed here in great detail:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

If *n* is the number of source_id's (and luckily *never > 21*), we make Postgres fetch the top 100 rows (according to `external_created_at DESC`) for each `source_id` from the index, which is very fast in itself, but max. *(n-1) * 100* rows are surplus. Given your value frequencies:

> 22,245 `source_id` with 1 to 1,543,950 rows - and 20,997,027 rows total

(You didn't clarify whether all of these numbers include "deleted" rows, but only ~ 25% are "deleted".)

... I'd expect some of the `source_id`'s to have less than 100 rows to begin with. So we only have to sort 2100 rows *in the worst case* (typically much fewer) to keep the top 100. That shouldn't perform so badly - once you have configured Postgres with decent resource settings.

If you have a source table holding all distinct `source_id`, it might make sense to use it and eliminate non-existent `source_id` early:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   source s, LATERAL ( ... ) p
WHERE  s.source_id IN (19082, 19075, 20705, ...)
ORDER  BY ...
```

A maximum of 21 `IN` values is ok for this form, but consider this related question:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in/91539#91539)

You could optimize some more if you *know* the minimum `external_created_at` or the maximum number of rows from a single `source_id` in the result ...

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response. This makes sense. It didn't even occur to me to use lateral. I will mess around with the settings/indexes and report back my findings.

Comment: @goddamnyouryan: I'd love to see timings for the new query / with and without new settings.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I finally got a chance to test this and it is looking great! Here are the response times for the 4 queries: `185.120 ms`, `101.785 ms`, `209.970 ms`, `18.885 ms`

Comment: @goddamnyouryan: This is without changes to the Postgres configuration or `CLUSTER` on the new index, right?

Comment: That's correct. I probably won't cluster in production, but i will tune the postgres config and likely make it even faster.

Comment: @goddamnyouryan: If performance is crucial, you might cluster once in a while at low traffic hours. Pity you can't install `pg_repack` on Heroku (from what you wrote in the Q).

Comment: Well I contacted them about `pg_repack` and they ignored that part of my question so I guess it's not possible. Always possible to move over to RDS though. And honestly, these response times are 2 orders of magnitude faster than they previously were, so I am still extremely happy. Thanks so much for your help. I can't say how much I appreciate it.

Comment: I am running into one issue when I try to add an offset: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125958/offset-and-limit-on-complex-query

Answer (score 1):

The reason queries #3 and #4 run faster than #1 is probably simply that whatever order they get the rows in (dictated by the value of `created_at`), they get 100 records matching the condition on `source_id` quite fast (you must have more records with those `source_id`s created early), while #1 must scan through **a lot** of rows before finding 100 matches.

The reason it picks that index instead of that on `source_id` depends on a number of factors, including the spread of the `source_id` values, the proportion of records where `deleted_at` is `NULL` and your `STATISTICS` settings on the table. It seems that in most cases, it thinks that the partial index (which helps fulfil the `deleted_at IS NULL` condition) helps more than the index on `source_id`.

You should probably add a partial index on `source_id` with condition `deleted_at IS NULL`. You can create it concurrently to avoid a lock:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY posts_source_id_where_deleted_at_is_null_idx
    ON posts(source_id)
    WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
```

Hopefully, it will then always use this index, which should give the quickest execution plan.

Alternatively, you could use a CTE ([`WITH` queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html)) to act as an optimisation guard in your queries and split the conditions in two parts: `source_id` first (which would use your existing index), then `deleted_at` (which would filter through the results of the first query). But if you have a large proportion of `deleted_at IS NOT NULL` rows, this will be less efficient than the new partial index.

Comment: I realize I had missed the `ORDER BY external_created_at desc` part of your queries (which also explains the choice of index). It is quite difficult to optimise a query based on orthogonal conditions and sort orders, though that may depend on the expected data and your exact needs. One option would be to have a partial index on `source_id,created_at`, and do a two-level query: `UNION` of a `SELECT ... WHERE source_id=x AND deleted_at IS NULL ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 100` for each of the `source_id` values, then an additional `ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 100` on top.

Comment: ... which can be simplified into a `LATERAL` join ... basically the idea of the solution I suggested. Your comment is back on target.