# Postgres JOIN conditions vs WHERE conditions

Tags: postgresql, join, optimization

Postgres newbie here.

I'm wondering if this query is optimized or not? I tried to JOIN ON only the values that are 100% necessary and leaving all the dynamic conditions in the WHERE clause. See below.

```
SELECT *
    FROM
      myapp_employees
    JOIN myapp_users ON
      myapp_users.user_id=myapp_employees.user_id
    JOIN myapp_contacts_assoc ON
      myapp_contacts_assoc.user_id=myapp_users.user_id
    JOIN myapp_contacts ON
      myapp_contacts.contact_id=myapp_contacts_assoc.contact_id
    WHERE
      myapp_contacts.value='test@gmail.com' AND
      myapp_contacts.type=(1)::INT2 AND
      myapp_contacts.is_primary=(1)::INT2 AND
      myapp_contacts.expired_at IS NULL AND
      myapp_employees.status=(1)::INT2 AND
      myapp_users.status=(1)::INT2
    LIMIT 1;
```

Note: For context, this proc is checking to see if a user is also an employee (elevated privs/different user type).

Anyways, is this the right way to go? Should the JOIN ON contain more statements like checking for expired_at IS NULL, for example? Why or why doesn't this make sense?

Comment: What about your version of Postgres? (`SELECT version();`)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3.14. Should this be something that I require in each function?

Comment: No, we here on dba.SE require of you to declare relevant software versions, because they make a difference for many questions.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Logically**, it makes no difference at all whether you place conditions in the join clause of an `INNER JOIN` or the `WHERE` clause of the same `SELECT`. The effect is the same.

(Not the case for `OUTER JOIN`!)

While operating with default settings it also makes no difference for the **query plan or performance**. Postgres is free to rearrange predicates in `JOIN` & `WHERE` clauses in its quest for the best query plan - as long as the number of tables is not greater than the [**`join_collapse_limit`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-JOIN-COLLAPSE-LIMIT) (default `8`). Details:

- [Complex view becomes slow when adding ORDER BY in outer query with small LIMIT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125985/complex-view-becomes-slow-when-adding-order-by-in-outer-query-with-small-limit/126656#126656)

For **readability and maintainability** it makes sense to place conditions that connect tables in the respective `JOIN` clause and general conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Your query looks just fine. I would use table aliases to cut back the noise, though.

Minor detail:

`int2 '1'` or even `1::int2` are more sensible than `(1)::INT2`. And while comparing to a value of well defined numeric data type, a plain numerical constant `1` is good enough, too.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of points..

1. If you're joining on a condition by the same name (`user_id`) in your case, you can use `USING (user_id)` rather than `ON (a.user_id = b.user_id)`. This also saves a redundant column from potentially being outputted (if you're running `SELECT *` in production).
2. `1::int2` is problematic. Either `status`, and `is_primary` and others are already `int2` in which case the literal 1 will be automatically be casted to int2, or int2 casted to int as pg sees fit. Or, if you're storing them as regular ints, and casting them down as if that made a difference in computation -- which it doesn't, the cast alone makes that a losing proposition.
3. When possible, all of the ::int2 should probably be stored as `boolean`. Then you can write your `WHERE` condition to be simpler too.
4. For your type and status, you may want an `ENUM` type.