# How do I debug Postgres' join strategy?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, execution-plan, postgresql-performance, datatypes

In the process of optimizing a Postgres query, I ran into a situation where two equivalent, simple queries execute in very different amounts of time. While I can't provide a reproducible example for this part, the queries look like:

**Query 1**, fast:

```
select a.id
  from a
  join b on a.id = b.id
  where a.id in ('1', '2', '3')
```

**Query 2**, slow:

```
select a.id
  from a
  join b on a.id = b.id
  where b.id in ('1', '2', '3')
```

The only difference being whether `a.id` or `b.id` is referenced in the where clause. (`b.id` is `unique` but `a.id` is not, if it matters.) Both tables are quite large, but the `id` columns are indexed.

The reason why Query 2 is running slowly is because Postgres is using a hash join. In Query 1, the planner chooses a nested loop, which is obviously much faster with such a selective condition.

Looking at the query plans (provided below) I can see that the predicted selectivities / row counts are relatively accurate - actually more accurate in the slower query. In other words, Postgres is not choosing a hash join strategy because it thinks there are more results for the condition than there are.

So, my question is: **how can I debug why Postgres chose this hash join strategy? How do I find out why the query planner doesn't consider (or overestimates) Query 1's plan when presented with Query 2?** `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is great but it doesn't allow me to see the plans that *weren't* used.

#### Query plans

Query 1 (fast):

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..1528.79 rows=344 width=17) (actual time=0.042..0.210 rows=21 loops=1)                                                                    
  ->  Index Only Scan using a_id_idx on a  (cost=0.56..19.71 rows=344 width=17) (actual time=0.027..0.049 rows=21 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{"1","2","3"}'::bpchar[]))                                            
        Heap Fetches: 0                                                                                                                                           
  ->  Index Only Scan using b_pkey on b  (cost=0.43..4.39 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=21)                   
        Index Cond: (id = (b.id)::bpchar)                                                                                                 
        Heap Fetches: 0                                                                                                                                           
Planning Time: 0.136 ms                                                                                                                                           
Execution Time: 0.227 ms
```

Query 2 (slow):

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Gather  (cost=1013.81..292692.84 rows=20 width=17) (actual time=704.293..1847.182 rows=21 loops=1)                                                                                             
  Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                                           
  Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                                          
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=13.81..291690.84 rows=8 width=17) (actual time=669.269..1822.987 rows=7 loops=3)                                                                                        
        Hash Cond: ((a.id)::bpchar = b.id)                                                                                                                             
        ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using a_id_idx on a  (cost=0.43..281065.62 rows=4042599 width=17) (actual time=0.019..1086.251 rows=3238563 loops=3)
              Heap Fetches: 0                                                                                                                                                                  
        ->  Hash  (cost=13.34..13.34 rows=3 width=17) (actual time=0.072..0.073 rows=3 loops=3)                                                                                                
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB                                                                                                                                     
              ->  Index Only Scan using b_pkey on b  (cost=0.43..13.34 rows=3 width=17) (actual time=0.040..0.068 rows=3 loops=3)                                    
                    Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{"1","2","3"}'::bpchar[]))                                                                  
                    Heap Fetches: 0                                                                                                                                                            
Planning Time: 0.391 ms                                                                                                                                                                        
Execution Time: 1847.219 ms
```

Comment: Apparently the condition on `a.id` only yields 21 rows, but without that condition, it assumes that all rows need to be retrieved and only then they can be filtered through the join. The planner is not smart enough to see that the condition on `b.id` could be rewritten to a condition on `a.id`

Comment: What is your Postgres version?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name version 12.5. And yes, I know that the planner cannot rewrite the condition, but since it predicts in advance that the condition on `b.id` will only yield 3 rows, why doesn't it do the same? (You can see in the query plan `Index Only Scan using b_pkey on b ... rows=3`)

Comment: Note that neither query's plan changes at all by swapping the two tables between `from` and `join`, so the planner should be able to filter on `b.id` first.

Comment: Actual table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) would be instrumental, like for most questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I find out why the query planner doesn't consider (or overestimates) Query 1's plan when presented with Query 2? `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is great but it doesn't allow me to see the plans that `weren't` used.

You can "disable" various planner methods to see alternative plans. *"Disable"* quoted, because those methods are then not actually disabled, just estimated to be ridiculously high, so that any other plan seems favorable. **Only for debugging!** Not meant for permanent use.

There is a list in the manual in the chapter [***Planner Method Configuration***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE). Consider the advice at the top:

> These configuration parameters provide a crude method of influencing
> the query plans chosen by the query optimizer. If the default plan
> chosen by the optimizer for a particular query is not optimal, a
> *temporary* solution is to use one of these configuration parameters to force the optimizer to choose a different plan. Better ways to
> improve the quality of the plans chosen by the optimizer include
> adjusting the planner cost constants (see [Section 19.7.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS)),
> running [`ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) manually, increasing the value of the
> [`default_statistics_target`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-DEFAULT-STATISTICS-TARGET) configuration parameter, and
> increasing the amount of statistics collected for specific columns
> using `ALTER TABLE SET STATISTICS`.

In your particular case, to understand why Postgres chose the this plan and not some other plan, compare the estimated costs before and after disabling the hash join strategy. Spoiler alert: it's because it (falsely) projects a lower cost. For instance:

```
EXPLAIN <Query 2>;  -- take note
SET enable_hashjoin = off;
EXPLAIN <Query 2>;  -- compare
```

Or use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for more details. You seem to be familiar with [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html).

Another plan will be chosen, and the estimated cost will be higher. And one or both estimates are pretty far from reality. ***Why*** Postgres arrives at bad estimates is another question. Basic starters are in the advice from the manual above.

Maybe your installation is (also) too optimistic about costs for parallelism. There are a number of [GUC parameters to adjust](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS) that. You can [disable parallelism](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-MAX-PARALLEL-WORKERS-PER-GATHER) for testing with:

```
SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0;
```

#### Force a particular order of joins?

For the added question in the comment:

> see the costs for performing scans in a Nested Loop in the opposite order?

You could experiment with [`join_collapse_limit`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-JOIN-COLLAPSE-LIMIT):

> Setting it to 1 prevents any reordering of explicit JOINs. Thus, the
> explicit join order specified in the query will be the actual order in
> which the relations are joined. Because the query planner does not
> always choose the optimal join order, advanced users can elect to
> temporarily set this variable to 1, and then specify the join order
> they desire explicitly. For more information see [Section 14.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-joins.html).

So:

```
SET join_collapse_limit = 1;
EXPLAIN <Query 2>; 
EXPLAIN <Query 2 with tables reversed>;  -- compare
```

Related:

- [Postgres JOIN conditions vs WHERE conditions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155972/postgres-join-conditions-vs-where-conditions/155976#155976)
- [Are implicit joins as efficient as explicit joins in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198182/are-implicit-joins-as-efficient-as-explicit-joins-in-postgres/198282#198282)

#### [Don't use data type `char(n)`!](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

One avoidable problem in your setup becomes obvious in the added casts in the `EXPLAIN` plan:

> ```
>  Index Cond: (id = (b.id)::bpchar)
> ```

Etc.

At least one `id` column is of type `character`. `bpchar` is the internal name for the outdated SQL data type `character`. "bpchar" for "blank padded character". Never use it. *Especially* not for PK columns. The type `character` is a Zombi you shoot in the head on sight.

Do not confuse `character` / `char` / `bpchar` with the useful data types `text` or `varchar` or `"char"` (with quotes!). See:

- [Any downsides of using data type “text” for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/939860)

If your id columns hold integer numbers, use `integer` (or `bigint`). Else `text` or whatever is appropriate.

Might contribute to the inferior query plans.
*Turned  out to be the main issue. See [OP's follow-up with a bug report](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/4158832.1618591790%40sss.pgh.pa.us#9f03e623ca834a1f103f4d92180d484a).*

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! I'm guessing not, but is there anything along these lines that would allow me to see the costs for performing scans in a `Nested Loop` in the opposite order? That seems to be where my issue lies--without a hash join, it's still scanning the entirety of table a before scanning table b with the condition.

Comment: @zmbc: Maybe with `join_collapse_limit = 1`. Not sure. I added info above.

Comment: Good idea but no dice. After trying it, it looks like `join_collapse_limit` merely constricts the order of the join *operations* when there are multiple, not the order of tables within a join.

Comment: Even though my question wasn't about the actual problem but how to debug it, you still managed to get it right. It turned out that one of the join columns being of type bpchar, while the other was a varchar, was (somehow) the cause of the query planner's mistake. Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's a nice outcome! :) Not the first time I have come across ripples in performance caused by joins on distinct data types (in combination with indexes).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it turned out to be--implicit casts were preventing indexes from being used. For anyone from Google in the future, here are all the gory details: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/4158832.1618591790%40sss.pgh.pa.us#9f03e623ca834a1f103f4d92180d484a

Comment: @zmbc: Always good to be in line with Tom! Though he would *nuke the
bpchar columns from orbit* and I only wanted to shoot them in the head on sight. Guess I'll have to step it up a notch. :)