# Optiziming complex Postgres query with filter

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization, performance, postgresql-performance

So I have asked about [this query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174830/index-query-with-limit-order-one-one-column-predicate-on-another) before and I got a really insightful answer. However I'd like to be able to further segment this query on `Postgresql 9.6.3` and it starts to slow down again. I'm not sure that a partial index will help here because it's not from a boolean value.

So this is the base query that is performing very well:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT posts.*
FROM unnest('{17858,50909,52659,50914,50916,51696,52661,52035,17860,53315,54027,53305}'::int []) s(source_id),
  LATERAL
  (SELECT "posts".*
   FROM "posts"
   WHERE (source_id = s.source_id)
     AND ("posts"."deleted_at" IS NOT NULL)
     AND "posts"."rejected_at" IS NULL
   ORDER BY posts.external_created_at DESC
   LIMIT 100) posts
ORDER BY posts.external_created_at DESC
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 1;
                                                                                QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=30895.79..30896.04 rows=100 width=1043) (actual time=5.299..5.337 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=30895.78..30920.78 rows=10000 width=1043) (actual time=5.297..5.325 rows=101 loops=1)
         Sort Key: posts.external_created_at DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 110kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..30512.87 rows=10000 width=1043) (actual time=0.085..4.077 rows=738 loops=1)
               ->  Function Scan on unnest s  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.016 rows=12 loops=1)
               ->  Limit  (cost=0.56..303.12 rows=100 width=1043) (actual time=0.018..0.298 rows=62 loops=12)
                     ->  Index Scan using index_posts_for_moderation_queue on posts  (cost=0.56..7628.00 rows=2521 width=1043) (actual time=0.017..0.285 rows=62 loops=12)
                           Index Cond: (source_id = s.source_id)
 Planning time: 0.443 ms
 Execution time: 5.433 ms
(11 rows)
```

And this is the modified one, with filter, that is much slower:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT posts.*
FROM unnest('{17858,50909,52659,50914,50916,51696,52661,52035,17860,53315,54027,53305}'::int []) s(source_id),
  LATERAL
  (SELECT "posts".*
   FROM "posts"
   WHERE (source_id = s.source_id)
     AND ("posts"."deleted_at" IS NOT NULL)
     AND "posts"."deleted_by" = 'User'
     AND "posts"."rejected_at" IS NULL
   ORDER BY posts.external_created_at DESC
   LIMIT 100) posts
ORDER BY posts.external_created_at DESC
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 0;
                                                                                      QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=551390.03..551390.28 rows=100 width=1043) (actual time=769.522..769.522 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=551390.03..551391.78 rows=700 width=1043) (actual time=769.521..769.521 rows=0 loops=1)
         Sort Key: posts.external_created_at DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5513.47..551363.28 rows=700 width=1043) (actual time=769.508..769.508 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Function Scan on unnest s  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.022 rows=12 loops=1)
               ->  Limit  (cost=5513.47..5513.48 rows=7 width=1043) (actual time=64.122..64.122 rows=0 loops=12)
                     ->  Sort  (cost=5513.47..5513.48 rows=7 width=1043) (actual time=64.120..64.120 rows=0 loops=12)
                           Sort Key: posts.external_created_at DESC
                           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on posts  (cost=5485.28..5513.37 rows=7 width=1043) (actual time=64.104..64.104 rows=0 loops=12)
                                 Recheck Cond: ((source_id = s.source_id) AND (deleted_at IS NOT NULL) AND (rejected_at IS NULL) AND ((deleted_by)::text = 'User'::text))
                                 Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1
                                 Heap Blocks: exact=9
                                 ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=5485.28..5485.28 rows=7 width=0) (actual time=64.098..64.098 rows=0 loops=12)
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_posts_for_moderation_queue  (cost=0.00..59.47 rows=2521 width=0) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=168 loops=12)
                                             Index Cond: (source_id = s.source_id)
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_posts_on_deleted_by  (cost=0.00..5425.55 rows=291865 width=0) (actual time=76.855..76.855 rows=334200 loops=10)
                                             Index Cond: ((deleted_by)::text = 'User'::text)
 Planning time: 0.348 ms
 Execution time: 769.660 ms
(21 rows)
```

The only difference between the two is that the second as the `AND "posts"."deleted_by" = 'User'` part additionally added to the lateral query.

The problem is where the value 'User' is, that is not a boolean value, and can be anything.

Is there a way to further optimize this query so that it will be speedier, even with the deleted_by query set?

Here's the db structure and indexes and settings:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    source_id integer,
    message text,
    image text,
    external_id text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    external text,
    like_count integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    comment_count integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    external_created_at timestamp without time zone,
    deleted_at timestamp without time zone,
    poster_name character varying(255),
    poster_image text,
    poster_url character varying(255),
    poster_id text,
    position integer,
    location character varying(255),
    description text,
    video text,
    rejected_at timestamp without time zone,
    deleted_by character varying(255),
    height integer,
    width integer
);

CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_source_id_and_external_created_at ON posts USING btree (source_id, external_created_at DESC) WHERE deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND rejected_at IS NULL;
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_deleted_at ON posts USING btree (deleted_at);
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_deleted_by ON posts USING btree (deleted_by);
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_source_id ON posts USING btree (source_id);
```

The first of the indexes above being a result of the answer I got to my last question.

**Postgres memory settings:**

```
name, setting, unit
'default_statistics_target','100',''
'effective_cache_size','16384','8kB'
'maintenance_work_mem','16384','kB'
'max_connections','100',''
'random_page_cost','4',NULL
'seq_page_cost','1',NULL
'shared_buffers','16384','8kB'
'work_mem','1024','kB'
```

**Database stats:**

```
Total Posts: 20,997,027
Posts where deleted_at is null: 15,665,487
Distinct source_id's: 22,245
Max number of rows per single source_id: 1,543,950
Min number of rows per single source_id: 1
Most source_ids in a single query: 21
Distinct external_created_at: 11,146,151
```

**EDIT**

I tried out the simplified answer I got from Evan with different source ids and it's pretty slow:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM posts AS p
WHERE source_id IN (159469,120669,120668,120670,120671,120674,120662,120661,120664,109450,109448,109447,108039,159468,157810)
  AND deleted_at IS NOT NULL
  AND deleted_by = 'Filter'
  AND rejected_at IS NULL
ORDER BY external_created_at DESC
LIMIT 100;
                                                                                                                                QUERY PLAN                                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=74114.14..74114.19 rows=100 width=1060) (actual time=2794.981..2794.981 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=74114.14..74115.48 rows=2678 width=1060) (actual time=2794.981..2794.981 rows=0 loops=1)
         Sort Key: external_created_at DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on posts p  (cost=68759.42..74093.67 rows=2678 width=1060) (actual time=2794.977..2794.977 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((source_id = ANY ('{159469,120669,120668,120670,120671,120674,120662,120661,120664,109450,109448,109447,108039,159468,157810}'::integer[])) AND (deleted_at IS NOT NULL) AND (rejected_at IS NULL) AND ((deleted_by)::text = 'Filter'::text))
               Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 32326
               Heap Blocks: exact=16019
               ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=68759.42..68759.42 rows=2678 width=0) (actual time=2745.376..2745.376 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_posts_for_moderation_queue  (cost=0.00..830.64 rows=52637 width=0) (actual time=42.319..42.319 rows=272192 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (source_id = ANY ('{159469,120669,120668,120670,120671,120674,120662,120661,120664,109450,109448,109447,108039,159468,157810}'::integer[]))
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_posts_on_deleted_by  (cost=0.00..67928.46 rows=6942897 width=0) (actual time=2651.123..2651.123 rows=7863994 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((deleted_by)::text = 'Filter'::text)
 Planning time: 0.856 ms
 Execution time: 2795.033 ms
(15 rows)
```

The reason I am using `LATERAL` can be explained by [another earlier question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124790/optimize-a-query-with-small-limit-predicate-on-one-column-and-order-by-another) I made optimizing this query.

Comment: come on, whitespace format your select statements.

Comment: @EvanCarroll whoops sorry. looks like we both edited it at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried extending your index with the column from the new predicate? `CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_source_id_and_external_created_at ON posts USING btree (source_id, external_created_at DESC, deleted_by) WHERE deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND rejected_at IS NULL;`

Comment: What kind of values do you store in `deleted_by`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right from the query, fix some of this up. Try this instead.

1. Stop using double quotes. None of this should be double quoted.
2. Don't ever say ", LATERAL". That's SQL-89 JOIN syntax. Time to update it. Those are all `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`
3. Don't use string literals for ints. Just do ARRAY[].
4. Don't use a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` when you can rewrite it to an `INNER JOIN`.
5. Don't use an `INNER JOIN` on literals when you can rewrite it to a `WHERE x IN ()`.
6. Don't use `WHERE x IN` when the list comes from SQL. Use `EXISTS` (this isn't applicable here, but if I'm ranting...).

Try this.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT posts.*
FROM posts AS p
WHERE source_id IN (17858,50909,52659,50914,50916,51696,52661,52035,17860,53315,54027,53305)
  AND deleted_at IS NOT NULL
  AND deleted_by = 'User'
  AND posts.rejected_at IS NULL
ORDER BY posts.external_created_at DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

## Update

Your big problem with that query is simply the `deleted_by`. Here is my advice.

These are your current indexes,

```
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_source_id_and_external_created_at ON posts USING btree (source_id, external_created_at DESC) WHERE deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND rejected_at IS NULL;
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_deleted_at ON posts USING btree (deleted_at);
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_deleted_by ON posts USING btree (deleted_by);
CREATE INDEX index_posts_on_source_id ON posts USING btree (source_id);
```

There is no reason to have `index_posts_on_source_id_and_external_created_at`, and `index_posts_on_source_id`. They both cover first source_id. so delete `index_posts_on_source_id` It's just slowing down inserts.

Second your big problem `deleted_by`. There are two ways to fix that.

1. One is a compound index so we don't have to do two index scans and bitmap merge them together.
2. Is a predicate index.

If `deleted_by` can only be a few types of values, you may look at creating it as an `enum` type and removing the string comparison.

Comment: The double quote stuff all comes from Rails, I agree, ugly. Should have cleaned it up. As for getting rid of the reason to use the `LATERAL`, this db has 10s of millions of posts, doing it without the `LATERAL` is slow. You can see where I got this from from another question from a few years ago: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124790/optimize-a-query-with-small-limit-predicate-on-one-column-and-order-by-another

Comment: I edited the question with the results of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of your answer, hopefully will give a little context for why I am using `LATERAL`

Comment: Thanks for the update. I went with the compound index, seems to have worked wonders.

Answer (score 1):

`PostgreSQL` is getting mislead into thinking that using the index `index_posts_on_deleted_by` is going to be helpful, when it is actually counter-productive.

It would take a really deep dive to figure out what is actually wrong in the planner to make it get confused.  Part of it is probably simply that it doesn't know how popular your values of source_id are, and is overestimating by a factor of 10, but I don't think that that is the whole story.  The quick and dirty solution is just to prevent the index from being used.  If no other queries need `index_posts_on_deleted_by`, you could just drop it.  If that is not the case, you can change your query to prevent it from being used for that query by changing:

```
     AND posts.deleted_by = 'User'
```

to

```
     AND posts.deleted_by||'' = 'User'
```

Or, the index Lennart suggested might be enough to provide a more-attractive-looking option to the planner.  Another index that would certainly help is:

```
(source_id, deleted_by, external_created_at)
```

Or

```
(deleted_by, source_id, external_created_at)
```

But those ones would not support the query which omits the deleted_by clause, so you would then have to keep both indexes around to support both queries.