# Very slow WHERE IN query on very large table - postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql

My table (with 140 000 000 rows) :

```
CREATE TABLE attendees(
  attendee_id                 VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  name                        VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  status                      VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  event_id                    VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (attendee_id, event_id)
);

CREATE INDEX attendees_event_id ON attendees(event_id);
CREATE INDEX attendees_attendee_id ON attendees(attendee_id);
```

My query :

```
SELECT event_id FROM attendees 
where attendee_id IN (SELECT attendee_id FROM attendees where event_id=$eventId)
```

This query can take several minutes.
I saw here: [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in) I can change the `IN` by `IN (VALUES (..)...)` but I don't know how to change this sub query :

```
SELECT attendee_id FROM attendees where event_id=$eventId
```

to have `(VALUES (..)...)`

So, my question is, what is the best way to make this query faster ?

edit (I run the explain (analyze, verbose) on smaller table):

```
Hash Join  (cost=5296.72..14097.38 rows=209116 width=16) (actual time=177.516..362.851 rows=121564 loops=1)
  Output: attendees.event_id
  Hash Cond: ((attendees.attendee_id)::text = (attendees_1.attendee_id)::text)
  ->  Seq Scan on public.attendees  (cost=0.00..5051.21 rows=230721 width=33) (actual time=0.572..90.302 rows=230721 loops=1)
        Output: attendees.event_id, attendees.attendee_id
  ->  Hash  (cost=4664.54..4664.54 rows=50574 width=17) (actual time=176.611..176.611 rows=49650 loops=1)
        Output: attendees_1.attendee_id
        Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2917kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.attendees attendees_1  (cost=1288.37..4664.54 rows=50574 width=17) (actual time=14.141..151.031 rows=49650 loops=1)
              Output: attendees_1.attendee_id
              Recheck Cond: ((attendees_1.event_id)::text = '1193751294041282'::text)
              Heap Blocks: exact=595
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on attendees_event_id  (cost=0.00..1275.73 rows=50574 width=0) (actual time=13.265..13.265 rows=49650 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((attendees_1.event_id)::text = '1193751294041282'::text)
Planning time: 1.611 ms
Execution time: 371.431 ms
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to achieve with that query. `select event_id from attendees where event_id = $eventId` should be functionally equivalent to your existing query.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Instead of the two single-column indexes, create one index on (`event_id, attendee_id)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I already have a PRIMARY KEY on (event_id, attendee_id)

Comment: No, you have a primary key on `(attendee_id, event_id)`  The order of the columns in an index matters. The index on only `(attendee_id)`  is useless because Postgres can also use the PK index for that. And the index on `(event_id)` can be replaced by one on `(event_id, attendee_id)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Drop the extra indexes
Reverse the order of the PK to PRIMARY KEY (event_id, attendee_id)

```
SELECT a1.event_id 
FROM attendees a1
JOIN attendees a2
  ON a2.event_id    = $eventId
 and a2.attendee_id = a1.attendee_id
```

Answer (score -1):

To Speed up the query,

We may use `join` instead of `subquery`

Try this query:

```
SELECT a1.event_id 
FROM attendees a1
JOIN attendees a2
    ON a1.attendee_id = a2.attendee_id
        and a2.event_id = $eventId
```

To make is faster check that if you can create CLUSTER on that table with index on Primary key

Note: cluster a table according to an index [reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-cluster.html)

Comment: This is effectively faster (3 minutes instead of more than 10) but still slow...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name When would it not return the same information?  event_id is part of the PK

Comment: @LoannDelgado Your table does have 140 000 000 rows

Comment: @Paparazzi Indeed

Comment: @downvoter please care to comment why down vote.