# Show values from list that are NOT returned by query

Tags: postgresql, select

I have been given a list of values that may or may not be found in a table's column. I just need the subset of the list that is NOT found in a `SELECT` query.

Pretending that the list I was given is: `'something_a', 'something_b', 'something_c', 'something_d'`...

My intuition is to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT item FROM ('something_a', 'something_b', 'something_c', 'something_d') 
WHERE item NOT IN (
    SELECT appropriate_column FROM some_table 
    WHERE appropriate_column IN ('something_a', 'something_b', 'something_c', 'something_d') 
);
```

I would expect to get back the following result if say two of the items are missing from the table:

```
item
---
something_a
something_c
```

What is a valid SQL approach to accomplishing what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`VALUES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html) clause to create a "constant table":

Let's assume this is your table:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table
(
    appropriate_column TEXT
) ;
```

populated with:

```
INSERT INTO 
    some_table (appropriate_column)
VALUES 
     ('something_b'),
     ('something_d') ;
```

This is how you would make the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    v 
FROM
    (
    VALUES
        ('something_a'),
        ('something_b'),
        ('something_c'),
        ('something_d')
    ) AS vs(v)
WHERE
    v NOT IN 
    (SELECT 
        appropriate_column 
    FROM
        some_table
    ) ;
```

You can check everything at [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4efa1f6e49dfd5f63a5b6dd8dec64659)

Comment: This works perfectly but seems unintuitive to me, particularly because the FROM clause becomes a list of single-item tuples, and also because I'm not sure where the variable `vs` comes from.

Comment: But consider [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=46b3cd3d1e86a029c19076df383574a6) with a NULL value in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Rather [stay away from `NOT IN`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN). If the column isn't defined `NOT NULL`, a single `NULL` value can kill the query. I suggest one of these:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

You can pass your list as array for convenience. See:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in/91539#91539)

```
SELECT *
FROM   unnest('{something_a, something_b, something_c, something_d}'::text[]) v(appropriate_column)
LEFT   JOIN tbl t USING (appropriate_column)
WHERE  t.appropriate_column IS NULL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=46b3cd3d1e86a029c19076df383574a6)*